# Debugging a JavaScript code run through ngrok

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm running a JavaScript code through a ngrok tunnel in the Windows Power Shell, as I'm using this code as webhook in Dialogflow.

I would like to debug the code now, as I want to see how it works step by step, receiving and processing the information that gets from Dialogflow.

However, when I use the debugging option of my code editor (Visual Studio Code in my case), the only thing it does is to open a window in the browser showing that the connection is successful, but it gets frozen there and never hits the breakpoint.

Is there any way to debug the code, so maybe I can enter information in Dialogflow and see how the JavaScript code receives it and processes it step by step?

Sorry not to post any code, but my problem is not in the code itself.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have the following launch.json file:

```
{"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }]}
```

I don't get any error message when I start debugging. Just after pressing F5, my browser (Chrome) opens and shows me that the connection is successful:

[image]

So I guess the tunnel is alright, but I don't get any console output either. It is like the VSCode just opens the browser and forgets about the debugging.

Comment: What is an "npm tunnel"?

Comment: the conection I'm using to the local host

Comment: That screenshot you added displays some output of the `ngrok` tool. That has nothing to do with the `npm` package manager.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*I'm running a JavaScript code through a tunnel*"? How did you start the actual server with the javascript code? That's what matters, not how something connects to it.

Comment: I'm first running the command `npm run dev` and then the tunnel. Then I put the https address in the fulfillment of Dialogflow.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not been very clear, I'm trying to continue a code that is not mine and I'm struggling quite a lot with JS

Comment: You need to check (in the package.json) what `npm run dev` is actually running, and then debug *that*. The tunneling is irrelevant.

Comment: Alright, I have ´"dev": "nodemon --inspect app2.js"´ in my package.json file, being app2.js the script I actually want to debug. But I don't know how to debug it as the usual debugging of Visual Studio Code (F5) doesn't hit the breakpoints.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include that info, and also post your vscode debug configuration please?

Comment: Also, do you get an error message when trying to debug? If not, what parts *do* work? Is it only breakpoints, but you get console output fine? Is it only requests coming from the tunnel, but local requests hit breakpoints as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I start debugging, my browser (Chrome) opens

Yeah, that's the culprit. Your selected debug configuration is for debugging of clientside javascript, therefore it opens the browser and connects to the debugger of the webpage. Nothing interesting happening there.

You'll need to [change your configuration to debug node.js instead](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging). See also the [VS Code recipe for debugging with nodemon](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/nodemon) as an example.

Comment: Thanks! Seems pretty useful! I'll go through the info in those links :)